# как получить доступ к элементу списка, которы находится в arraylist

Tags: c#

```
ArrayList a = new ArrayList
            {
                new List<int>(5)
            };
```

как получить доступ например ко 2 элементу list

Comment: ArrayList это лютейшее легаси, для чего вы используете эту коллекцию? Может здесь имеет место XY-проблема?

Comment: я просто изучаю коллекции

Comment: Довольно просто не правда ли: `((List<int>)a[0])[1]`

Answer (score 1):

ArrayList - это список объектов разных типов(вернее тип то у них один, `object`, общий для всех), поэтому чтобы обратиться к элементу, нужно явно приводить его к нужному типу.

```
ArrayList a = new ArrayList
{
    new List<int>(5)
};

if (a.Count > 0)
{
    var list = a[0] as List<int>;
    if (list != null)
    {
        if (list.Count > 1)
        {
            var elem = list[1];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: понятно, спасибо